# creating selectable list of users?

Tags: 7

On the content pages/nodes, there is a block that shows a list of the logged in user's friends. I need to make this list selectable so that the user can mark specific users and share/send the page to them.

Scenario: User1 is logged in and looking at an article. On the article page, a list of all their friends is available but clicking on the friend's name takes to that friends profile. I need to allow user1 to select one or more friends from this list and send them the node link through notification or email.

Is it even possible with block? If so, how? Or any other way of achieving the same?